# How to fix unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse in express.js server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am getting error while sending POST request to api from angular application.
[image]

Angular :-

```
   public saveBlog(blog: any) {
        console.log(blog);
        return this.http.post(host+"/core/api/blogs",blog).toPromise();
      }
```

Express code :-

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '5mb' }));
app.use(errorHandler());
app.use("/core/api",blog );


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server started at 3000");
});
```

Comment: It means that your json is not valid. Check the response from your API.

Comment: I'm directly sending a JavaScript object

Comment: then try to visualize either the post parameters or the response (in the network tab of your devtools). Find why the json is not valid.

Comment: what are you sending from your `blogs` route?

Comment: Based on the information in the error message, your response from the API is text, not JSON. You need to handle that. This may help you: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data, and this: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post. Specifically, Overload #3.